# How to map an existing folder in my local drive to Azure File Share storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm studying Azure File Share Storage. I can see that I can map my File Share Storage as a Network drive in my PC using the below command:

```bsh
$ net use [drive letter] \\ppolstorage.file.core.windows.net\cloud-drive 
  /u: [storage account access key]
```

But is there any way to map an existing folder in my local drive, for example `Test Folder` in `D Drive` to Azure File Share Storage? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this done, but it appears to work using a Directory Symbolic Link.  EG:

```
C:\>mklink /D c:\share \\mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net\share
```

Answer (score 1):

> But is there any way to map an existing folder in my local drive, for
>   example Test Folder in D Drive to Azure File Share Storage? Is this
>   possible?

Technically it should be possible using [`Azure File Sync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-deployment-guide#transfer-data-into-azure-files) though it is more suited for your on-prem file shares (i.e. essentially a server product) instead of mapping a folder in a local drive on your computer.